# Grouping items in php

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with sorting items in table in PHP. Here is what I want to achieve :

```
Item    Item    Item
Item    Item    Item
Item    Item    Item
Item    Item    Item
Item    Item    Item
```

How I mean to achieve this, well since I have a for each loop I can insert counter, and say after 5th item is listed write to another column, the thing is I'm not good with tables, I've tried something like :

```
for(...)
$counter++;
if(($counter%5) == 0){
echo "";
}
```

Not happening .. I hope you understood what I meant .. tnx

Comment: So you don't mean *sorting* but, lets call it, *grouping*.

Comment: @Felix You're right sorting is something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want this:

```
Item1    Item6    Item11
Item2    Item7    Item12
Item3    Item8    Item13
Item4    Item9    Item14
Item5    Item10   Item15
```

If you're doing this in a table, you'd be going across then down, so you'd need to draw every fifth item before jumping down a row.

```
$numItems = count($items);
$numRows = 5;
$numColumns = ceil($numItems / $numRows);

echo "<table>";
for ($r = 0; $r < $numRows; ++$r) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($c = 0; $c < $numColumns; ++$c) {
        $itemIndex = $c * $numRows + $r; // 0, 5, 10, 1, 6, 11, 2, 7, 12...
        echo "<td>";
        if (isset($items[$itemIndex])) {
            echo $items[$itemIndex];
        } else {
            echo "&nbsp;";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```